# capturing data in html form and storing data into excel or access

Tags: html, excel, ms-access

1. html form will have questionaire
2. students fill out the questionaire and submit them
3. the data would be saved into excel or access

Is it possible to store data in excel or access if we just have html form?

thanks

Comment: When you say "just html form," does that mean you can't use server-side code?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc, yes correct. just html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You need a server-side program to process the form and generate the appropriate binary file. HTML is not even a programming language.